# All element deleted after a specific $_POST

Tags: php

I would know how to rectify this element because when I delete a product, this is all the row inside the table are deleted in the option table.
I tested just one with the value 262, but I can have some.

If you need more information . tell me.

Thank you

my class in products directory to delete one or some products.
At the end the class call a hooks.

This class works very fine. 
look this : $OSCOM_Hooks->call('Products','DeleteAll'); this element allow to use it in other directory to delete products_id in other table (like specials, options, favorites ....)

Products class to delete the products (one on some).

```
class DeleteAll extends \ClicShopping\OM\PagesActionsAbstract {
    protected $app;
    protected $selected;
    protected $cPath;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->app = Registry::get('Products');

        $this->selected = $_POST['selected'];
        $this->cPath = HTML::sanitize($_GET['cPath']);
    }

    public function execute()  {
        $OSCOM_ProductsAdmin = Registry::get('ProductsAdmin');
        $OSCOM_Hooks = Registry::get('Hooks');

        if (!is_null($this->selected)) {
            foreach ($this->selected as $items) {
                if (isset($items)) {
                    $Qcheck = $this->app->db->prepare('select count(*)
                            from :table_products_to_categories
                    where products_id = :products_id
                    ');
                    $Qcheck->bindInt(':products_id', (int)$items);
                    $Qcheck->execute();

                    if ($Qcheck->rowCount() > 0) {
                        $OSCOM_ProductsAdmin->removeProduct($items);
                        $OSCOM_Hooks->call('Products','DeleteAll');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $this->app->redirect('Products&cPath=' . $this->cPath);
    }
}
```

Option class where there is an id of products table

This is this class give me a problem when I select one or some products to delete. The row of the table is all deleted.

result on `var_dump($item)`

```
/.../Save.php:58:null ==> correct
/.../DeleteAll.php:35:string '262' (length=3)
```

the value is 262 and it's correct but when the class (below) is executed, all the the row inside the table is deleted.
than i don't understand, I have just one value 262 = items but all the row inside the table is deleted.

```
class DeleteAll implements \OM\Modules\HooksInterface {
    protected $app;
    protected $selected;

    public function __construct() {
        if (!Registry::exists('ProductsAttributesNew')) {
            Registry::set('ProductsAttributesNew', new ProductsAttributesNewApp());
        }

        $this->app = Registry::get('ProductsAttributesNew');
        $this->selected = $_POST['selected'];
    }

    public function execute()  {
        $this->app = Registry::get('ProductsAttributesNew');

        if (isset($this->selected)) {
            foreach ($this->selected as $items) {
                if (!is_null($items) && is_numeric($items)) {
                    var_dump($items);

                    $this->app->db->delete('test_products_option', ['products_id' => (int)$items]);
                    $this->app->db->delete('test_products_option_value', ['products_id' => (int)$items]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'all the elements inside the table are deleted' - you mean all the rows in the table are deleted ?

Comment: What value does `(int)$items` contain ans what is the definition of the `delete` function ? Are you using any framework ?

Comment: Hi Kathy, you need to share more code. Also may the name of your file explains (DeleteAll.php) why its happening maybe you are including the wrong class in code.

Try to share what exactly $this->app->db->delete does, also is your $items an array or an string why are you casting to int. May be you should check that.

Comment: @ErsinDemirtas I inserted some information. $this->app->db->delete, is is the same thing if you write sql delete row. the result of $items must be a number.